# Javascript - Page displays only after button clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, scope

The first problem is that the page isn't displayed when the button is clicked the first time. The second - related problem is that there's an error "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined" the first time the button is clicked, although everything is fine when the button is clicked twice.

main.js

```
var surveyPage = '';
var surveyQuestions = '';
var surveyPageData = '';

var fakeDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );

function get_surveyPageHtml(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        surveyPage = data;

        fakeDiv.innerHTML = '';
        fakeDiv.innerHTML = data;

    });
    surveyQuestions = '';
    surveyQuestions = fakeDiv.getElementsByClassName('question');
    console.log(surveyQuestions);

    surveyPageData = surveyQuestions[1].innerHTML;
    console.log(surveyPageData);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    url = "page/page.html";
    $("#button").click(function(){   

        get_surveyPageHtml(url);
        $("#display").html(surveyPage); 

    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="button">Get page data</button>
    </div>

    <div id="display"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

page/page.html

```
<h2>Survey</h2>

<label class="question">Question 1</label>
<label class="question">Question 2</label>
<div class="question">
    Question 3
    <label class="question">Question 4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit to your problem is:

```
get_surveyPageHtml(url);
$("#display").html(surveyPage);
```

AJAX requests take time, and you are trying to use the response before the AJAX request has completed.  You can solve this by moving `$("#display").html(surveyPage);` here:

```
//...
$.get(url, function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    surveyPage = data;

    fakeDiv.innerHTML = '';
    fakeDiv.innerHTML = data;

    $("#display").html(surveyPage);
})
```

That way, the page is loaded when the AJAX response comes in.

--edit--

The reason you're getting `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` is the same from the first, just in a different block of code.  This is how you should do it:

```
function get_surveyPageHtml(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        surveyPage = data;

        fakeDiv.innerHTML = '';
        fakeDiv.innerHTML = data;
        $("#display").html(surveyPage);

        surveyQuestions = '';
        surveyQuestions = fakeDiv.getElementsByClassName('question');
        console.log(surveyQuestions);

        surveyPageData = surveyQuestions[1].innerHTML;
        console.log(surveyPageData);

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't solve the second part of the problem, though.

Comment: Updated to solve the 2nd problem.  Just make sure any code that is dependent from an AJAX request is either run directly within `$.get(url, function(data) {...});` or is called from that, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify something, your other statement also should go after ajax is completed.

```js
$.get(url, function(data) {

    // code...

    surveyQuestions = '';
    surveyQuestions = fakeDiv.getElementsByClassName('question');
    console.log(surveyQuestions);
    surveyPageData = surveyQuestions[1].innerHTML;
    console.log(surveyPageData);
}
```

If you're using jQuery, a good practice for your purpose, I recommend this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rr5UtYcHNTUf0cEMf9pc (Press Run and see main.js)